# How to resolve the name properly by BeanELResolver

Tags: java, jsp, resolver

we have to work with a very specific class in Java that has the following property:

```
protected SPSExchangedDocumentType spsExchangedDocument;

public SPSExchangedDocumentType getSPSExchangedDocument() {
  return spsExchangedDocument;
}
```

I use the instance of that class inside a jsp page:

`<c:out value = "${certificate.spsExchangedDocument.id.value}"/>`

It throws me the following exception:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class
>   'un.unece.uncefact.data.standard.spscertificate._5.SPSCertificateType'
>   does not have the property 'spsExchangedDocument'.    at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:579)  at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:281)     at
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
>     at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)   at
>   com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.evaluateExpression(PageContextImpl.java:1001)

I think the problem is directly with the fact, that the property is called **spsExchangedDocument**, but the method is called **getSPSExchangedDocument**. I cannot change the code of the class, because it's generated automatically from XSD, that we cannot alter, so I should change the page. But what name should I use in order for EL to resolve it properly:

- spsExchangedDocument.
- SPSExchangedDocument.
- sPSExchangedDocument.

What is the rule for such naming conventions in java and EL anyway?

Comment: In general, the naming of the getters and setters are the name of the property with the first character capitalized and preceeded with get/set. So please try it with getSpsExchangedDocument. Normally this can be generated by your IDE of choice.

Comment: Once again - I cannot change the name of the getter, because it's generated automatically by the Jaxb tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `BeanELResolver` implementation conforms to [the JavaBeans spec](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html):

> **8.8 Capitalization of inferred names.**
>
> Thus when we extract a property or event name from the middle of an
>   existing Java name, we normally convert the first character to lower
>   case. However to support the occasional use of all upper-case names,
>   we check if the first two characters of the name are both upper case
>   and if so leave it alone. So for example,
>
> - “FooBah” becomes “fooBah”
> - “Z” becomes “z”
> - “URL” becomes “URL”

The [java.beans API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html) resolves the property name as `SPSExchangedDocument`:

```
import java.beans.*;

public class Bean {
  public Object getSPSExchangedDocument() {
    return null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IntrospectionException {
    BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(Bean.class);
    for (PropertyDescriptor prop : info.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
      System.out.println(prop.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

*That said, there have been bugs in this area before.*